# Graphical representation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

How would you graphically represent the following complex functions on the Argand plane (ie. not polar coordinates):
$$|2i-z|=|z+1+3i|$$
and
$$Re[(3-4i)z]>0$$
I know that $|z-a|=c$ is a circle centred at a with radius c and $Re(z)>0$ is the right hand side of the plane, but how do I use these to graph the above functions?

Comment: One approach which is at times not too hard, just plug in $z=x+iy$ and square both sides. On the other hand, the second condition is better understood by placing $3-4i$ in polar form to understand the scalar multiplication as a dilation and rotation hence it's a half plane...

Comment: $Re(z)>0$ is the **right** hand side of the plane

Comment: Apologies, I did indeed get left and right confused there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|2i-z|$ represents the distance of $z$ from $2i$ and $|z+1+3i|$ represents the distance of $z$ from $-1-3i$. If the distance is the same then draw a line connecting these $2$ points. And then in the middle of this line draw another line perpendicular to it. This line represents your set.

For $z = x+yi$, $(3-4i)z = 3x+3yi-4xi + 4y$.

So $Re((3-4i)z) > 0 \iff 3x+4y>0 \iff y>-\frac{3x}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For $|2i-z|=|z+1+3i|$: Distance from $(0,2)$ = Distance from $(-1,-3)$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

For $Re[(3-4i)z]>0$: If you visualize the geometric notion of multiplication of $\mathbb{C}$ numbers and try to keep the product have a positive $X$, you will realize that $z$ lies in the half plane just missing the origin and farthest from the point $(-3,4)$. This approach works because of the linear nature of the equation. For complicated stuff it is easier to rely on the algebraic methods i.e. substituting $z=x+iy$. Anyhow you can always be sure that this kind of inequality will always result in a (may be non-existent) region.